# Read SIDs and set ACLs

Tags: powershell

The following script reads a set of SIDs inside firewall rules and uses them to set ACL rules in a folder.

The question is: Is this syntax ok or is there better ways to write this script, considering powershell syntax features? (by the way, this code works)

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory)]$foldername)

$result=""

(Get-NetFirewallRule | Where-Object { ($_.Direction -eq "Outbound") -and ($_.DisplayName -like "*appcontainer*")}) |
         %{ ($_ | Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter) | 
        %{  $acl = Get-Acl $foldername
            $sec= New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($_.Package)
            $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($sec,"FullControl",(1 -bor 2),0, "Allow") 
            $acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
            $acl | Set-Acl $foldername
          } }
```

Comment: nope! [*grin*]  **_[1] never use aliases or short names in a script that will be shared or reused._** why? code is READ far more often than written, so make it easy to read. **_[2] use consistent_ indents._** your indentation makes it needlessly unclear where each stage begins and ends. see **_[1]_** for why. **_[3] you need comments describing the purpose of the code._** again, someone who reads your code next month [perhaps you] needs some sort of idea as to the intent of your code.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey If you're writing a review, the answer section is much more appropriate for that.

Comment: @Mast - my comment doesn't seem up to "Answer" levels. it is mostly restating the PoSh best practice & style github stuff. do you think it worthy of being an "Answer"?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Well, it's a good start of an answer. Flesh it out a bit and you got something worthy of the answer box, absolutely.

Comment: @Mast - done ... thank you for the nudge! [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nope! [grin]

this is almost entirely about style, not performance. you will note that most points are about readability ... the following line is quite true ...

***better readability gives better understanding gives better maintainability.***

[1] never use aliases or short names in a script that will be shared or reused
why? code is READ far more often than written, so make it easy to read.

[2] use consistent indents
your indentation makes it needlessly unclear where each stage begins and ends. see [1] for why that is important.

[3] you need comments describing the purpose of the code
again, someone who reads your code next month [perhaps you] needs some sort of idea as to the intent of your code.

[4] avoid long lines
you have two lines that run well off to the right. since PoSh *knows* that things like pipe symbols WILL be followed by more stuff, you can wrap after such. that also applies to commas, open parens, and other such "more to come" items.

why bother? once again, it is about *reading*. there is a reason why most wide-format publications to use multiple columns ... people tend to read more comfortably when the lines require minimal side-to-side eye movement. that works out to about 80 to 100 chars per line.

make use of the *vertical* space you have available. folks scan vertically somewhat more easily than horizontally.

[5] use consistent variable case
you use `lowercase` and `PascalCase`. try to stick with ONE such style ... and `PascalCase` is the one usually recommended.

[6] read the officially referenced *unofficial* style & best practices guide
this ...

PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle: The Unofficial PowerShell Best Practices and Style Guide
— https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle

[7] remove unused code
you define `$Result` ... but never use it. i would remove that.

[8] define the type for your parameter
your `$FolderName` parameter type is not defined. i suspect it is `[string]`, tho.

[9] avoid sending things across a pipe if you can
you send `$_` to `Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter` via a pipe. pipeline ops are slower than direct ops & it looks like you could call that out by using the parameter name directly.

---

here's how i would rework your code layout ...

```
Param (
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory)]
        [string]
        $FolderName
    )

Get-NetFirewallRule |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Direction -eq "Outbound" -and
        $_.DisplayName -like "*appcontainer*"
        } |
    ForEach-Object {
        # i wonder if the next two lines could be done as 
        #    Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter -AssociatedNetFirewallRule $_
        $_ |
        Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter | 
        ForEach-Object {
            $Acl = Get-Acl $FolderName
            $Sec= New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($_.Package)
            $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
                $Sec,
                "FullControl",
                (1 -bor 2),
                0,
                "Allow"
                )
            $Acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
            $Acl |
                Set-Acl $FolderName
            } # end 2nd FE-O
        } # end 1st FE-O
```